# Mounting ipad in ubuntu 13.10 , can't find "Documents on iPad" device

Tags: mount, 13.10, ipad, ios

I solved the "trust-loop" bug with this help:
http://itsfoss.com/mount-iphone-ipad-ios-7-ubuntu-13-10/

But after my ipad is successfully mounted, I found out there is only one device detected but it's just some digital files there, like DCIM etc.

I can't find the Documents on iPad device which contain apps folders.

I want to transfer files to the apps in my iPad. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Just rebooting the Ipad is working.
Look at the Rainer's commentary there :  http://itsfoss.com/mount-iphone-ipad-ios-7-ubuntu-13-10/#comment-1268303764

Comment: For me, your comment did not help. I don't see where it has something to do with the "Documents ..." folder. Mounting the basic folder works for me, but not for the "Documents ..." folder. Just a guess: The reason may be that time moves on and we are beyond 13.10 and ios 7. Related:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/598940/libimobiledevice-1-2-ios-8-support-for-ubuntu-14-04-trusty

Answer (score 0):

Apple devices sync with itunes properly. For that, try downloading 'itunes' using 'wine' or 'play-on-linux'. You can follow "https://www.wikihow.tech/Download-iTunes-for-Linux" or any other guideline for it. That is what I do for my apple devices and is the safest and most reliable way to do it.