# Can't find "Documents on {username}'s iPad" in 12.04 with an iPad mini

Tags: 12.04, ipad, ios

I found this question for 13.10 : [Mounting ipad in ubuntu 13.10 , can't find "Documents on iPad" device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442511/mounting-ipad-in-ubuntu-13-10-cant-find-documents-on-ipad-device)

I solved my "trust-loop" issue as the link in that question suggested, by upgrading to libimobiledevice2 1.1.6 , but that completely broke down with a lot of errors when i connected my iPad.

So I downgraded back to 1.1.1-4 . Now when I connect my iPad, the "trust-loop" bug is gone, but I can only find the "{username}'s iPad" folder and not the "Documents on {username}'s iPad" folder. A post suggested rebooting my iPad which I did, with no success.

Please help! I really want to put some songs and movies on my iPad soon!

EDIT:

Ok! I reboot my laptop, and the "Documents" folder shows up, but the "trust-loop" problem is back again. :(

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you should reinstall libmobiledevice again. "Documents on [user] iPad" reappears after rebooting the ipad.

Comment: This answer is rather incomplete. Can you explain how and why it'll help?