# libimobiledevice 1.2 (iOS 8 Support) for Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty

Tags: ppa, ios

Is there a PPA available for the most recent libimobiledevice 1.2 version with support for iOS 8 or can someone explain how to build it from source without messing up everything?

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libimobiledevice

Comment: I didn't find any, but it's not hard to build and package the current version yourself: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpdatingADeb.

Comment: Thanks I guess I will have to try it out then. I'm little bit concerend about breaking the integration with nautilus.

Comment: Have you been successful with it? Are you able to mount the "Documents of..." folder again? I managed to build and install, but mounting and charging did not work at all. Therefore, I downgraded and wait for someone more skilled to set up a ppa.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/).

Bear in mind, each step works only if the previous step was successful.

1. Clone the repository

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/src
   cd ~/src
   git clone https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice.git
   cd libimobiledevice
   ```
2. Install the necessary development libraries

   You may need more libraries or header packages as listed below. You will see this if you have error messages during the configuration step later. Add a comment if you have problems.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libusbmuxd-dev libplist-dev  libplist++-dev libgnutls-dev libssl-dev python-dev
   ```
3. Install some additional software

   The following software is needed to prepare the software for compilation and then compile it.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install usbmuxd make automake autoconf libtool pkg-config gcc
   ```
4. Install optional software

   The following software is used to make parts of the finished package a run faster and create documentation.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install cython doxygen
   ```
5. Install an installation helper

   Checkinstall creates a debian package so the software is managed by the package manager.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install checkinstall
   ```
6. Configure and build

   ```
   ./autogen.sh
   make
   ```
7. Install

   With the command below, a deb package with the name `libimobiledevice` will be created and installed.

   ```
   sudo checkinstall
   ```

   You will see this warning:

   ```
   checkinstall 1.6.2, Copyright 2009 Felipe Eduardo Sanchez Diaz Duran
              This software is released under the GNU GPL.



   *****************************************
   **** Debian package creation selected ***
   *****************************************

   *** Warning: The package version "1.2.1
   1.2.1
   1.2.1
   1.2.1
   1.2.1
   1.2.1
   1.2.1
   1.2.1
   1.2.1
   1.2.1" is not a
   *** Warning: debian policy compliant one. Please specify an alternate one


   This package will be built according to these values: 

   0 -  Maintainer: [ root@aboettger-VirtualBox ]
   1 -  Summary: [ Package created with checkinstall 1.6.2 ]
   2 -  Name:    [ libimobiledevice ]
   3 -  Version: [  ]
   4 -  Release: [ 1 ]
   5 -  License: [ GPL ]
   6 -  Group:   [ checkinstall ]
   7 -  Architecture: [ i386 ]
   8 -  Source location: [ libimobiledevice ]
   9 -  Alternate source location: [  ]
   10 - Requires: [  ]
   11 - Provides: [ libimobiledevice ]
   12 - Conflicts: [  ]
   13 - Replaces: [  ]
   ```

   Simply press <kbd>3</kbd> and type `1.2.1` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   ```
   Enter a number to change any of them or press ENTER to continue: 3
   Enter new version: 
   >> 1.2.1
   ```
8. Check the installed files

   ```
   dpkg -L libimobiledevice
   ```

   and you will see something like this

   ```
   /.
   /usr
   /usr/share
   /usr/share/doc
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/COPYING.LESSER
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/AUTHORS
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/NEWS
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/README
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/docs
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/docs/idevice_id.1
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/docs/idevicenotificationproxy.1
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/docs/idevicepair.1
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/docs/ideviceprovision.1
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/docs/ideviceimagemounter.1
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/docs/Makefile
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/docs/idevicedebug.1
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/docs/idevicename.1
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/docs/idevicebackup.1
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/docs/idevicedebugserverproxy.1
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/docs/ideviceenterrecovery.1
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/docs/idevicecrashreport.1
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/docs/ideviceinfo.1
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/docs/Makefile.in
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/docs/Makefile.am
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/docs/idevicescreenshot.1
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/docs/idevicedate.1
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/docs/idevicesyslog.1
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/docs/idevicediagnostics.1
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/docs/idevicebackup2.1
   /usr/share/doc/libimobiledevice/COPYING
   /usr/local
   /usr/local/bin
   /usr/local/bin/idevicepair
   /usr/local/bin/idevicename
   /usr/local/bin/ideviceinfo
   /usr/local/bin/idevicebackup2
   /usr/local/bin/ideviceprovision
   /usr/local/bin/idevicecrashreport
   /usr/local/bin/ideviceimagemounter
   /usr/local/bin/idevice_id
   /usr/local/bin/idevicenotificationproxy
   /usr/local/bin/ideviceenterrecovery
   /usr/local/bin/idevicescreenshot
   /usr/local/bin/idevicediagnostics
   /usr/local/bin/idevicedebug
   /usr/local/bin/idevicebackup
   /usr/local/bin/idevicedebugserverproxy
   /usr/local/bin/idevicesyslog
   /usr/local/bin/idevicedate
   /usr/local/lib
   /usr/local/lib/libimobiledevice.la
   /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
   /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libimobiledevice-1.0.pc
   /usr/local/lib/libimobiledevice.so.6.0.0
   /usr/local/lib/libimobiledevice.a
   /usr/local/share
   /usr/local/share/man
   /usr/local/share/man/man1
   /usr/local/share/man/man1/idevicebackup2.1.gz
   /usr/local/share/man/man1/ideviceprovision.1.gz
   /usr/local/share/man/man1/idevicebackup.1.gz
   /usr/local/share/man/man1/idevicecrashreport.1.gz
   /usr/local/share/man/man1/idevice_id.1.gz
   /usr/local/share/man/man1/ideviceenterrecovery.1.gz
   /usr/local/share/man/man1/ideviceimagemounter.1.gz
   /usr/local/share/man/man1/idevicename.1.gz
   /usr/local/share/man/man1/idevicescreenshot.1.gz
   /usr/local/share/man/man1/idevicedebug.1.gz
   /usr/local/share/man/man1/idevicenotificationproxy.1.gz
   /usr/local/share/man/man1/idevicedebugserverproxy.1.gz
   /usr/local/share/man/man1/idevicedate.1.gz
   /usr/local/share/man/man1/ideviceinfo.1.gz
   /usr/local/share/man/man1/idevicesyslog.1.gz
   /usr/local/share/man/man1/idevicediagnostics.1.gz
   /usr/local/share/man/man1/idevicepair.1.gz
   /usr/local/include
   /usr/local/include/libimobiledevice
   /usr/local/include/libimobiledevice/syslog_relay.h
   /usr/local/include/libimobiledevice/lockdown.h
   /usr/local/include/libimobiledevice/diagnostics_relay.h
   /usr/local/include/libimobiledevice/screenshotr.h
   /usr/local/include/libimobiledevice/property_list_service.h
   /usr/local/include/libimobiledevice/installation_proxy.h
   /usr/local/include/libimobiledevice/restore.h
   /usr/local/include/libimobiledevice/file_relay.h
   /usr/local/include/libimobiledevice/mobile_image_mounter.h
   /usr/local/include/libimobiledevice/mobilebackup2.h
   /usr/local/include/libimobiledevice/afc.h
   /usr/local/include/libimobiledevice/service.h
   /usr/local/include/libimobiledevice/webinspector.h
   /usr/local/include/libimobiledevice/heartbeat.h
   /usr/local/include/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice.h
   /usr/local/include/libimobiledevice/mobilesync.h
   /usr/local/include/libimobiledevice/misagent.h
   /usr/local/include/libimobiledevice/debugserver.h
   /usr/local/include/libimobiledevice/mobilebackup.h
   /usr/local/include/libimobiledevice/house_arrest.h
   /usr/local/include/libimobiledevice/sbservices.h
   /usr/local/include/libimobiledevice/notification_proxy.h
   /usr/local/lib/libimobiledevice.so
   /usr/local/lib/libimobiledevice.so.6
   ```

Comment: Are you able to mount the "Documents of..." folder again? Does is work with ios 9 / 10?

Answer (score 9):

OK, this is what worked for me.

The order is:

```
libplist -> libusbmuxd -> libimobiledevice -> usbmuxd, ifuse, ideviceinstaller, ...
```

Source: https://github.com/libimobiledevice/usbmuxd/issues/10

```
mkdir -p ~/src
cd ~/src

sudo apt-get -y install libusbmuxd-dev libplist-dev libplist++-dev libgnutls-dev libssl-dev usbmuxd make automake autoconf libtool pkg-config gcc cython doxygen checkinstall libusb-1.0-0-dev libssl-dev

git clone https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libplist.git
cd libplist/
./autogen.sh 
make
sudo make install

cd ..
git clone https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libusbmuxd.git
cd libusbmuxd/
./autogen.sh 
make
sudo make install

cd ..
git clone https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice.git
cd libimobiledevice/
./autogen.sh 
make
sudo checkinstall
```

In `checkinstall` prompt:

```
> y[ENTER]
> [ENTER]
> 3[ENTER]
> 1.2.1[ENTER]
> [ENTER]
```

Comment: Worked like magic on 18.04

Comment: Had to also install this https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice-glue on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 8):

This is what I did to build libimobiledevice-1.2.0:

1. Install build tools and dependencies

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot devscripts pbuilder
   sudo apt-get build-dep libimobiledevice
   ```
2. Download the source and Debian build scripts of the currently packaged version (1.1.5 on Ubuntu 14.04):

   ```sh
   apt-get source libimobiledevice
   cd libimobiledevice-1.1.5
   ```
3. Scan for and download new upstream version:

   ```sh
   uscan --verbose
   ```
4. Unpack it, put the Debian build scripts in place and update the change log:

   ```sh
   uupdate ../libimobiledevice_1.2.0.orig.tar.bz2
   cd ../libimobiledevice-1.2.0
   ```
5. Build the binary package (in parallel with as many workers as available CPU cores):

   ```sh
   debuild -b -j$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN)
   ```

   (`-j` instructs the build system to run individual build tasks in parallel, if possible. Since this sometimes leads to problems, it may be worthwhile to try to re-run the build without that flag or to drop it in the first place.)
6. Install the built package:

   ```sh
   sudo dpkg -i ../libimobiledevice_1.2.0*.deb
   ```

Actually I cheated a bit. I couldn't satisfy the build dependencies, because a library isn't available in sufficiently recent versions in Ubuntu 14.04: libimobiledevice-1.2.0 requires `libusbmuxd-dev (>= 1.0.9)`, so you'll have to build it from source first with the same recipe.

Comment: While trying to build the upgraded libusbmux-d, after adding some dependencies, I ran into:
dh_auto_configure --  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/usr" -DCMAKE_SKIP_RPATH=true -DLIB_SUFFIX= -DUSB_PKGCONF_INCLUDE_DIRS="/usr/include/libusb-1.0"
configure: error: unrecognized option: `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr'

Any idea?
Is there some chance that you (or others) will post the result of you efforts in a ppa?

Comment: Please [open a new question](/questions/ask) for your issue. You can send me a link through this comment sections to draw my attention to it. As a quick idea, consult the output of `./configure --help` for a list of available options.

Comment: Actually, someone else did this, because they run into the same problem... https://askubuntu.com/questions/616501/why-did-debuild-fail-with-configure-error-unrecognized-option

Comment: fyi, it fails on `debuild -b` step with "dh_install: libimobiledevice4 missing files (usr/lib/*/*.so.4*), aborting" on Ubuntu *15.04*

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 15.04. Did you get a solution?

Comment: To install `libusbmuxd-dev (>= 1.0.9)` you can download the *.deb [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/amd64/libusbmuxd-dev/1.0.9-1) and install it with `sudo dpkg -i`

Comment: @Michele dependencies problem

Comment: @DavidFoersteryour instruction doesn't work under 14.04. It'd be better to upload debs

Comment: @yanpas Didn't work for me either, but this one did: http://askubuntu.com/questions/670130/how-to-compile-libimobiledevice-1-2-on-ubuntu-15-04/672018#672018

Answer (score 3):

I use this PPA, it has latest libimobiledevice, but not all components are represented there: https://launchpad.net/~martin-salbaba/+archive/ubuntu/ppa+libimobiledevice

Comment: What components are missing? Those that enable viewing apps' shared documents?

Comment: @NoBugs yes, ifuse misses

Comment: Does not work on 15.10.

Answer (score 1):

16.04 will have 1.2. I was able to download the debs from launchpad (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/libimobiledevice) and install them on 15.10. I needed `libusbmuxd4`, `libimobiledevice6`, and `libimobiledevice-dev`. Then I installed ifuse 1.1.3 by following these directions: https://askubuntu.com/a/691758