# How to mount an iphone 5s to Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, mount, iphone

I am completely new to linux so I need things spelled out for me. I'm trying to mount an iphone 5s with ios 8.3 to Ubuntu 14.04 running Nvidia drivers.

Comment: The thing is, with Apple devices, you will probably want to use latest Ubuntu releases bor better results. Not saying it will work but mounting Apple devices has been posible since Ubuntu 10.04...until iOS updates and break support, and then a new Ubuntu release bring it back and then an ending story.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iOS 8 requires libimobiledevice-1.2, which is not available as packet for 14.04 imho. Instructions on how to install [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598940/libimobiledevice-1-2-ios-8-support-for-ubuntu-14-04-trusty)

Answer (score 3):

First, let me apologize for this information not being as complete as I would like it.

The following is confirmed to work on Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet):

1. Install the required support libraries:

   sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils usbmuxd ifuse
2. You will want to reboot due to udev entries updated per "usbmuxd".
3. The following commands are used to pair you iPhone/iPad devices to your 
   PC:

   ```
   mkdir /media/iphone
   chown {your userID}:{your groupID} /media/iphone
   chmod 775 /media/iphone
   /usr/bin/idevice_id -l
   ```

   (this command displays a 40 character identifier unique to your idevice)

   ```
   /usr/bin/idevicepair -u ## pair
   ifuse /media/iphone -u
   ```

   ...or you can simplify the last two lines by typing this:

   ```
   /usr/bin/idevicepair -u \`/usr/bin/idevice_id -l\` pair
   ifuse /media/iphone -u \`/usr/bin/idevice_id -l\`
   ```

This works for me :)

Comment: This no longer works in Ubuntu 16.04/iOS10.  Not sure which is the problem since I haven't mounted since 14.04/iOS9.  Error after running `ifuse /media/iphone -u ##`: "GnuTLS error: Error in the pull function. / Failed to connect to lockdownd service on the device. / Try again. If it still fails try rebooting your device."

Comment: after installing libimobiledevice this worked for me - im using kubuntu

Answer (score 1):

idevicepair and ifuse are the tools I used on Kubuntu 15.10 to mount my iphone 6 and transfer 40GB of pictures.

thank you

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I recently had to do it, if your device run iOS 10, you need to compile the latest idevicepair from github source. I followed this procedure https://gist.github.com/samrocketman/70dff6ebb18004fc37dc5e33c259a0fc

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am using kubuntu 16.04 and an iPhone 4s.

After installing the libraries like explained in previous questions and ifuse, when using ifuse my iPhone would still not mount. It wouldn't neither charge although it vibrated when connecting to my computer.

I solved this problem by restarting the usbmux process (http://www.phenomtech.net/2015/02/fix-non-charging-iphone-through-usb-on-ubuntu-linux.html):

```
ps aux | grep usbmux
sudo kill -9 xxxx
sudo usbmuxd -u -U usbmux
```

Where xxxx is the process id seen using "ps aux".

After restarting this process I could mount using ifuse (and access my photos) and my phone was charging too.