# Why did debuild fail with "configure: error: unrecognized option:"

Tags: ppa, ios, debuild

I was trying to follow the instructions listed in this question/answer.

[libimobiledevice 1.2 (iOS 8 Support) for Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598940/libimobiledevice-1-2-ios-8-support-for-ubuntu-14-04-trusty)

The answer said : "Actually I cheated a bit. I couldn't satisfy the build dependencies, because a library isn't available in sufficiently recent versions in Ubuntu 14.04: libimobiledevice-1.2.0 requires libusbmuxd-dev (>= 1.0.9), so you'll have to build it from source first with the same recipe."

I assumed that "build it from source first with the same recipe." meant to follow the same steps, substituting libusbmuxd-dev for libimobiledevice. I also assumed that I should do that before building lbimobiledevice.

I did that and get a fatal error in the debuild step 5. Being new to this, and after a lot of searching, I am at a loss for how to determine what the error is and what needs to be done to correct it. This is the first thing I have done after a new install of 14.04. So if someone can help it would be appreciated.

configure: error: unrecognized option: -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr'
Try./configure --help' for more information

```
stevie@Studio1:~/usbmuxd-1.1.0$ debuild -b -j$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN)
 dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc -b -j2
dpkg-buildpackage: source package usbmuxd
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 1.1.0-0ubuntu1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution UNRELEASED
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by StevieRay <stevie@Studio1>
 dpkg-source --before-build usbmuxd-1.1.0
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_clean
   dh_clean
 debian/rules build
dh build
   dh_testdir
   debian/rules override_dh_auto_configure
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/stevieray/usbmuxd-1.1.0'
dh_auto_configure --    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/usr" -DCMAKE_SKIP_RPATH=true -DLIB_SUFFIX= -DUSB_PKGCONF_INCLUDE_DIRS="/usr/        include/libusb-1.0"
configure: error: unrecognized option: `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr'
Try `./configure --help' for more information
dh_auto_configure: ./configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir=${prefix}/include --mandir=${prefix}/share/        man --infodir=${prefix}/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --        libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/        usr -DCMAKE_SKIP_RPATH=true -DLIB_SUFFIX= -DUSB_PKGCONF_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include/libusb-1.0 returned         exit code 1
make[1]: *** [override_dh_auto_configure] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/stevieray/usbmuxd-1.1.0'
make: *** [build] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1364:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc -b -j2 failed
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` option is missing for the `make`.
So in your `~/usbmuxd-1.1.0` add the complementary file
 `CMakeCache.txt`
and write in it:
 `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr`

Comment: Thanks but that seemed to have no effect. The results of the debuild command were identical.

Comment: As a test I removed the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH line from the configure_flags in the debian/rules file and the debuild failed on the next Cmake variable, -DCMAKE_SKIP_RPATH=true. It seems to have something to do with the override_dh_auto_configure but I am way over my head here.

Comment: you are true, and like you when I removed the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX, fault is on the next variable.
I am beginning building with the libplist-1.12 packet because building usbmuxd-1.1.0 go to
Requested 'libplist >= 1.11' but version of libplist is 1.10

Then I removed 
the -D characters at beginning for the 3 variables in configure_flags like below
configure_flags +=  CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr \
   CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=/usr/lib/$(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH) \
   Python_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS=$(PYVER)
and also comment the line
# dh_install --fail-missing
Now build go and ending on normal key error...

Comment: My apologies kalagani but I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @MartinC_47 Did your ever manage to solve this problem - I'm currently stuck in the same place?

Comment: @Andy Davies - No. Unfortunately not. I have put iOS support aside for the time being. Working on other deliverables in the meantime while waiting for a positive reply.

Comment: Same problem here...

Answer (score 0):

First, you tried to upgrade usbmuxd and not libusbmuxd-dev. (I ran into the same thing.)

Second, I downloaded libusbmuxd-dev (and some prerequisites) from the [ubuntu 15.10 repostiroy](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/i386/libusbmuxd-dev/1.0.9-1). Look for the appropriate version [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+package/libusbmuxd-dev).

So, building libimobiledevice-1.2.0 was possible for me. But be warned: I was not able to connect my iphone any longer. So I ended up, reinstalling older libraries from a ppa and wait for someone who knows it better and builds a ppa.