# Not sure how to get around build error (libimobiledevice 1.2)

Tags: 14.04, compiling, debuild

I'm running a VM of Ubuntu 14.04 32bit if this makes any difference...

I followed along with the answer from this question:

[How to compile libimobiledevice 1.2 on Ubuntu 15.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/670130/how-to-compile-libimobiledevice-1-2-on-ubuntu-15-04/672018#672018)

But I run into an error when trying to do

```
./autogen.sh
```

It said I needed a newer version of libplist so I followed the install instructions on libplists github page. That seemed to install with no problem and now that I got around that error, ./autogen.sh throws this error...

This is the last line of it running and then the error I get in the terminal...

```
#define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"

checking for libplist Cython bindings... no
configure: WARNING: cannot find libplist Cython bindings. You should  
install your distribution specific libplist Cython bindings package.
checking for openssl... no
configure: error: OpenSSL support explicitly requested but OpenSSL could 
not be found
```

Tried to do a sudo apt-get install openssl but it says it's already installed..

Comment: Use this answer, it works. http://askubuntu.com/a/672018/367165

Comment: Now I'm getting a different error... updating my question...

Comment: @A.B. Well, I got past all the errors. Got it installed, but ios-webkit-debug-proxy is still broke. Unable to retrieve device list. I give up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compile the code you need the development libraries of `libssl`. Installing `openssl` or `libssl` isn't enough. Therefore install `libssl-dev` via

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

After that, start

```
./autogen.sh
```

again.

Comment: Thanks. That got it installed, which let me install ios-webkit-debug-proxy finally. Sad news is that ios-webkit-debug-proxy still won't work for me. Just says "unable to retrieve device list"

Comment: I would say, that's enough for a new question.

Comment: How could this be done in macos?

Answer (score 2):

install package `libssl-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

then recompile code .