# Attempt to install libimobiledevice-1.2.0 throws error: "libimobiledevice4 missing files (usr/lib/*/*.so.4*), aborting"

Tags: 14.10, ppa, deb, ios, debuild

I'm building and installing libimobiledevice 1.2.0 following the instructions at: [libimobiledevice 1.2 (iOS 8 Support) for Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598940/libimobiledevice-1-2-ios-8-support-for-ubuntu-14-04-trusty/605198#605198) but I keep getting the error:

```
libimobiledevice4 missing files (usr/lib/*/*.so.4*), aborting
```

The full error:

```
dh_install --fail-missing
dh_install: libimobiledevice4 missing files (usr/lib/*/*.so.4*), aborting
debian/rules:19: recipe for target 'override_dh_install' failed
make[1]: *** [override_dh_install] Error 255
```

What could be causing this and how do I fix it?

**OS: Ubuntu 14.10**

Comment: @A.B. no, because it's still looking for a fix to the error of this way of building the deb

Comment: Retracted my vote. But maybe a part of an other answer is an answer, too. **;)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to solve it for that way of installing, but this one worked:

https://askubuntu.com/a/672018/350308

With one change, his line:

```
https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice.git
```

Should be:

```
git clone https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice.git
```

Comment: I have updated my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/672018/350308) and you could give me an upvote, because it works for you **;)**