# libimobiledevice build for kubuntu 14.10 went wrong

Tags: kubuntu, 14.10, ppa, iphone, ios

I tried following the instructions given in this question: [libimobiledevice 1.2 (iOS 8 Support) for Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty](https://askubuntu.com/q/598940/462920)
but something went wrong and this is what i got when i reached the eighth step:

> ~/src/libimobiledevice$ dpkg -L libimobiledevice
>   dpkg-query: package 'libimobiledevice' is not installed
>   Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
>   and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.

So yeah, not sure what this means, because i still can't link up my iPhone at all.  I thought I followed the directions properly, so not sure what to do now.

Comment: With this problem in step eight, you should have an error message in one of the previous steps.

Comment: Delete the extracted source folder. Run **all** steps again. Post the whole output here http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and give me the link.

Comment: I found the error: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13242964/  Something to do with OpenSSL

Comment: it tells me that i already have the newest version.  here's the paste link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13245349/

Comment: Answer added and corrected. Have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of the `./configure` script says

```
checking for openssl... 
no configure: error: OpenSSL support explicitly requested but OpenSSL could not be found
```

Install the necessary development library :

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

and after that ... do it again :

```
./autogen.sh
```

Comment: Thank you!  I see where I went wrong the first time.  you were very helpful.