# iPhone large file transfer via USB on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: usb, 16.04, iphone, transfer

Right now, I'm able to transfer large files only via the following two methods:

1) use an FTP or SFTP app and wait until I'm 80 for the file to transfer. I get about 3MB/sec through my wireless LAN, tops. Usually hovers around 1MB/sec.

2) Use my Mac.

Even in these cases, I'm not able to actually play the .mp4 files in the native player without jumping through hoops, but that's an iPhone question, not a Linux question.

My question is:

Is there *any* way to transfer the files using any package or library or script accessible through Ubuntu that goes over USB? It's almost six times faster.

Additonal requirements for an effective solution:

- Cannot use a VM, I already have a Mac that can do this. (In fact, it's actually faster for me to move the file to the Mac with a USB stick and then use iTunes than to try to transfer it over wifi.)
- same thing for Wine, and I couldn't get it to work anyway.
- Im fairly comfortable with the command line, and I'm even comfortable writing code if I have to, assuming there's a library that I can code against, with a decently clear API.
- a third party app (any free video player on the App Store) can **reach and play the file** once it's on the phone.

If it's impossible, I'll just get an Android. This is my last ditch effort to find an answer.

Thanks!

Note: I'm also unwilling to jailbreak the device, and it's on whatever the latest version available of iOS is.

Due to an oversight I completely forgot to mention the problem.

I'm perfectly able to use `libimobiledevice` to transfer the file. It just doesn't actually *do* anything. It takes up space on the device, but no application running on the device can access or even see the file. To reiterate, the intent of the question is to be able to *actually use* the file on the device from apps running on the device. If it's not possible, I understand.

Answer (score 4):

You need this : `libimobiledevice`

This is a cross-platform package which communicates with i-devices and get file-system access (and much more) and needs **no** jailbreaking.

Most recent version is 1.2.0 and you can read details here: [Official page : libimobiledevice.org](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/)

Coming to **installation**, there is already excellent description available here : [Mounting i-devices on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598940/libimobiledevice-1-2-ios-8-support-for-ubuntu-14-04-trusty)

After **mounting your iphone** like a USB device, you will be able to access the folders and then your transfer job will be just copy/paste thing.

---

If you are transferring a **video file** and it is not recognized by the default video app on iPhone, then the issue is with the file format including bitrate and frames per second. To solve this, one can simply convert to iPhone supported video format easily using `Handbrake` video encoder.

This application is available in the software repository and installation is easy using the the `Software center` on 14.04 or `Software` on 16.04.
In the application, choose '`iPhone and iPod touch`' shown in  Devices menu on the right.

(*  Most of the times it is noticed that the file size becomes smaller than original. If you have several files, you can queue them and convert all of them together.)

[image: Handbrake > Devices on the right > iPhone]

---

- After the transfer of the files, you need to the **Sync the folder** where you have placed  the file(s) in the particular application, say `iTunes` to get the new video(s) playable.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have posted that in the question and I will update my question to reflect your answer.

Comment: Updated question with additional details, sorry for the oversight.

Comment: Ok, i see. Did you install `ifuse` ?

Comment: Yeah. The auto-mounting works beautifully, I get nice pretty folders in a folder browser. I can transfer the file anywhere I want within that directory. But play (or even *find*) the video on the device? Can't do that.

Comment: So, can you transfer files using `ifuse` ?

Comment: Yes. I can transfer files but I cannot use them.

Comment: So the device is not recognising these transfered files. What kind of files (which formats) are you trying to find on the phone ?

Comment: .mp4's from various sources. They will play and be recognized when downloaded directly into the apps folders via iTunes but that's the only way to get them to be recognized.

Comment: Now I understand the issue. I will edit the post.

Comment: Ok, so I have it formatted properly enough that even the native video player will play it already. That's not the issue. The issue is that I cannot access the app folder it needs to go in from Ubuntu. It drops me into some other directory that apps cannot access.

Comment: Maybe you can try making a new folder and try to access it from the app first. Then later add files , then Sync on the app.

Comment: For details, it drops you into, I believe, the /media directory, and you cannot get out of that directory with a non jail broken device. Videos are stored in that directory, in a hashed folder setup. You can try to guess which folder the file should go into, but even if you get it right (I scripted a small video into *all of them*), the iPhone still won't recognize the file because it reads an encrypted database also present in that directory to know which videos it has. The only way to update that database is with the key in iTunes. That's as far as I got, my phone contract is up this month.

Comment: And that's for videos in the Videos app. There's no way at all to access any other app's folders. They're stored in /Applications or /Library, I think.

Comment: Even if I wanted to decompile the iTunes app and get at the key, decrypt the database, and reverse engineer the hashing scheme for the foldering, it would likely break when they update iOS. Not worth it.

Comment: Looks like really complex. If i find a work through i will update in the post. I 'll try with an iPad since iPhone broke.  :-(